# A question about "$\times$" notation with group actions

Tags: group-theory, notation, group-actions

[Per Wikipedia, a (left) group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#cite_note-1) is defined as follows:

> If $G $ is a group and $X$  is a set, then a (left) group action $φ$ of $G$ on $X$ is a function  $$\varphi : G \times X \to X : (g,x)\mapsto \varphi(g,x)\cdots
> $$ (and so on).

My question is, what is the meaning of the "$\times$" notation in this context? It immediately calls to mind direct products and cross products. If so, it is defined via two groups, but $X$ here is a set than group, so I have my doubts.

Comment: For the record, this is not the definition of a left group action, the crucial part of the definition is missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the [Cartesian product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of (the underlying set of) $G$ with $X$, *i.e.*, $$G\times X=\{(g, x)\mid g\in G, x\in X\}.$$

Answer (score 4):

It is the Cartesian product of the two sets $G$ and $X$.  The group structure on $G$ will then be used in the definition of an "action" (associativity and identity acts like an identity).

Answer (score 3):

The $\times$ here is not a cross product, but a *cartesian product* (an operation between sets). Here it indicates that the action $\varphi$ is actually a function that has the set $G \times X$ for its domain ($G \times X$ is the set of all pairs of an element of $G$ together with an element of $X$). Its codomain is $X$.

Or put it more simple, $\phi$ takes one element of the group $G$ and one element of the set $X$, and returns as output an element of $X$.